# Scala CQRS Framework

Tags: scala, cqrs

I'm looking for CQRS framework for Scala programming language.

The idea of using Scala is to avoid annotation hell that appears when Java frameworks such as [AxonFramework](http://www.axonframework.org/) are used.

Can you recommend some?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

See [Akka Persistance](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/persistence.html) and  also [eventsourced](https://github.com/eligosource/eventsourced)

Here are two tutorials using Akka:

- [Building an Event-Sourced Web Application - Part 1: Domain Model, Events and State](http://krasserm.blogspot.com/2011/11/building-event-sourced-web-application.html)
- [CQRS with Akka actors and functional domain models](http://debasishg.blogspot.com/2011/01/cqrs-with-akka-actors-and-functional.html)
- [Lagom](https://www.lightbend.com/lagom) (Java apis)

Comment: Also Akka-based and functional [Fun.CQRS](http://www.funcqrs.io/).